# Displaying database modifications on a web page using asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a piece of software which has a fairly complicated seeding method that takes 15+ minutes to run. Instead of running it on database migrations we have it available to be run manually through an administration panel.

This panel allows individuals running the software to upload a valid database and seed its data. That all works fine, but it leaves the webpage idling for an extended period of time with no indication of what is happening.

To clarify the process I want to display the output from the database log on the screen to let the administrator know how far into the seeding process they are. I've looked around fairly thoroughly and I haven't found any really effective method to display this data on the webpage. Does anyone know the best way I could do something like this?

Currently my seed method looks something like this

```
 public void Seed(LightHouse.DbContext.ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        context.Database.Log = message => Trace.WriteLine(message);
        var db = new GenericDatabase(ConnectionString, System.Data.OleDb.OleDbFactory.Instance);
        //Various methods which add database information
    }
```

I want to take the information displayed by context.Database.Log and print it to the view dynamically, preferably in a scrolling window.

Comment: Use AJAX to poll the server for log messages, or use SignalR to write them to the client in real time.

Comment: Yeah. What have you tried? THat is NOT a MVC Problem so much - you need a data source in MVC, but the updates dynamically are a typical javascript / SignalR etc. stuff. Not beginner level, but in any good book about the topic.

Comment: @mason websockets. Web socks sounds like Spiderman's footwear.

Comment: The problem I had with the progress bar solution is it's not easy to measure how long each segment of the seeding function will take, which would make the progress bar fairly inaccurate. I'm probably going to implement one, but I wanted to be able to display more thorough data to the administrator if possible.

Comment: I really hesitate to actually try to answer this question, as it's really broad. Perhaps you could rework it to be more narrow in scope. Maybe try to implement passing messages back to the client via AJAX or [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20), and let us know if you run into specific problems.

Comment: Fair enough, I know the question is probably too broad but I was unsure of which direction is best to go next. I'll try using SignalIR, I haven't experimented with that yet.